# How to use variable name in JSTL SQL tag

Tags: jsp, jstl

```
<%
    String datab = request.getSession().getAttribute("data").toString();
    System.out.println(datab);
%>
                        
<s:setDataSource driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+datab 
   user="root" password="MySQL@123" var="ds"></s:setDataSource>
```

The problem is how to add "datab" in url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "[JSP expression language](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_expression_language.htm)" syntax to display or use data in you page.

```
<s:setDataSource 
   driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" 
   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/${datab}" 
   user="root" 
   password="MySQL@123" var="ds"></s:setDataSource>
```

Comment: i already used it but for the case of scriptlet tag it is not working.

Comment: so for the new question appear instead of "${datab}" what can we written in <s:setDataSource> . under <s:setDataSource> tag scriptlet tag's variable not working

Comment: Did you try to use `url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/${data}"` without using the datab variable ?